# A form which allows users to select a template object in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on an application that allows users to manage financial documents and applications. Instead of having users fill out a list of fields in a form, users can click a checkbox next to each template application in a table. On submit, these applications will be added to the database and it's fields can be edited later.

At the moment I'm using a single Application model. All applications will have some fields in common, though each will have many unique fields as well. Should I be creating a separate model for each application, or is it fine to have a database table with many empty fields per record?

Each form is split into sections. For example, Personal Info, Contact Info, Address, Employment. So I was thinking that I may be able to somehow reuse these sections in each application object.

I'd also like to know how I should manage the creation of each application template. I was thinking of creating a application_template.rb file under lib (is that the right place?), and writing methods within that file for each application that will create a new Application object with the default fields. Then I can call those methods in the create action of ApplicationsController.

Please let me know if you require more information.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I suggest moving away from a relational database and I recommend you create your model in a key-value based data store, since your data will not have any integrity. MongDB and Redis are pretty popular. And they both have wrappers for Ruby.